# First npm package - tailwind css issue conflict between package and project

Tags: typescript, configuration, tailwind-css, npm-package

I have created my first npm package that utilises tailwind as a peer dependency. The issue I am having is that when I utilise my package in another project with tailwind, it is causing some overriding styles by adding a second tailwind style tag. I have checked the package's node_modules when installed in my project and there isn't a tailwind folder but there is a tailwind file in the .bin folder. There is also the tailwind.config.js and the css file I am using in my package for importing tailwind styles (which I guess might be the issue, although I am using tailwind styles in the package).

The package is on npm and here is the link to the github, so you can take a look at any code you may need to, although I am guessing it is most likely in the configuration files.

https://github.com/clovellbsc/Dropdown-Component